# VSCode SFTP Extension Using SSH Authentication как получить значение для параметра "agent" в Windows 10

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, sftp

Как получить значение для параметра "agent" конфигурационного файла sftp.json?
Без него у меня не соединяется с сервером!

Для Linux у меня это сработало так

```
"privateKeyPath": "/home/toorr2p/.ssh/id_rsa",
"agent": "/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh",
"passphrase": null,
```

В Linux я получил это значение командой

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Но как узнать этот путь в Windows?

[Здесь описано как это сделать для Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852476/visual-studio-code-sftp-extension-using-ssh-authentication/77044187#77044187)

Comment: Вроде как в первом абзаце в документации описано: https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp/wiki/SFTP-only-Configuration